# IOS AMSlideMenu open menu callback

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates, xcode5, protocols

I'm new in IOS, and can't understand some things about delegates and protocols. 
In my project I'm using [AMSlideMenu](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) for slide menu. I need to update same data in slide menu. For that I need to catch openMenu callback. In instruction for slide menu I found this

```
 If you want to get menu's open/close callbacks, then set MainVC's delegate property, and implement protocol named 'AMSlideMenuProtocols'. 

 @optional
 - (void)leftMenuWillOpen;
 - (void)leftMenuDidOpen;
 - (void)rightMenuWillOpen;
 - (void)rightMenuDidOpen;
```

I tried to catch callback with this code

```
//myClass.h    
#import "AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController.h"
#import "AMSlideMenuMainViewController.h"
@interface myClass : AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController<AMSlideMenuDelegate>

@end

//myClass.m
#import "myClass.h"

@interface myClass ()

@end

@implementation myClass
-(void)leftMenuWillOpen
{
    //something
}
@end
```

but `leftMenuWillOpen` never gets invoked. What I did wrong?

Comment: Have you set the delegate to AMSlideView?

Comment: No. I set it to AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController where table with my menu options

Comment: The object of myClass should be the delegate to AMSlideMenu  object

Comment: How can I do this if myClass object and AMSlideMenu object are created throw storyboard?

Comment: I did it! Thanks for your help, Shanti K!

Comment: I have added the same in the answer part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not setting the delegate to the slide menu. The object of myClass should be the delegate to AMSlideMenu object.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer and for a quick reference, you need to add this to your viewDidLoad :

```
self.mainSlideMenu.slideMenuDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0** compatible
This is my case, but I guess is the general situation:

```
class MainViewController: AMSlideMenuMainViewController, AMSlideMenuDelegate  {

  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.leftMenu = LeftMenuViewController(nibName:"LeftMenuViewController", bundle:nil)
    self.rightMenu = nil
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.slideMenuDelegate = self /* FOCUS HERE */
  }

  // MARK: - AMSlideMenuDelegate -

  func leftMenuWillOpen() {
    let menu = self.leftMenu as! LeftMenuViewController
    menu.centerMenuItems()
  }
}
```

Where **LeftMenuViewController** is a custom class that inherits from **AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController**.

Comment: @ Luca Davanzo Sir, hope you are doing well, can you please send me a implementation of AMSlideMenu tutorial link in swift