# AMSlideMenu Notify if side menu is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, amslidemenu

I am using AMSlideMenu library in my project and its really awesome. Everything is working good.I would really like to know how to identify whether the left side menu is opened or closed. The case is like, there is a textfield and even if i slide the screen to open the side menu or tap the top nav button to open side menu ,the keyboard remains open while the textfield is active. Is there a way to hide the keyboard or notify that the side menu is opened or closed

Comment: Please do check if this link helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981470/ios-amslidemenu-open-menu-callback/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get menu's open/close callbacks, then set MainVC's delegate property, and implement protocol named `AMSlideMenuDelegate` which declared in `AMSlideMenuProtocols.h`.

```
@optional
- (void)leftMenuWillOpen;
- (void)leftMenuDidOpen;
- (void)rightMenuWillOpen;
- (void)rightMenuDidOpen;
```

Do make sure that you have set the delegate to AMSlideMenu object.